# Can we make a looping random transform animation using noise in Blender?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, looping

[In this video](https://youtube.com/shorts/nlQMTgNRZgw) I'm using random transform for animation, but the result is so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other methods, like [Erindale's sine-wave looping](https://youtu.be/F2NcNJQZFqw?t=238), but here's a *Geometry Nodes* setup with less math where I mix two 4D `Noise Texture`s with identical values at different temporal phases (the *W* socket) tied to your desired beginning and end frame numbers:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I followed your node. It works very well. But is there a way to set how deep the z-axis translation is?

Comment: You should be able to control that with a Multiply node right before it goes into Set Position, no?